# Errors with SSL validation in Grails

Tags: grails, ssl-certificate

I want to make a post to an url with SSL validation in Grails.
I've imported the certificates, and I've generated the jks files.
But it seems Grails does not found those jks files.
Below is the code I'm executing (it's in a Grails Service Class):

```
def certificate = "mycert.jks"

def http = new HTTPBuilder(url)

def keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.defaultType)
getClass().getResource(certificate).withInputStream {
    keyStore.load(it, "test1234".toCharArray())
}

http.client.connectionManager.schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new SSLSocketFactory(keyStore), 443))
```

The error is 
"Cannot invoke method withInputStream() on null object"
so
the method getResource() is not working, and returns null.

I saw that this code, in a functionalTest Class, works fine.

Anyone knows how can I solve this problem?

Thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that non-source files from `grails-app/services` aren't copied into the classpath. This is the case for `src/java` though, but not `src/groovy`. It's also the case for `grails-app/conf`, but that's the only `grails-app` folder that this happens for, since it's the configuration file folder.

So your best bet is to move the file to `grails-app/conf` and use

```
Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResource(certificate).withInputStream {
    keyStore.load(it, "test1234".toCharArray())
}
```

Comment: I've tried also with Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(certificate) but I still having the same problem (returns null)

Comment: Is this in run-app, or in a deployed war, or unit or integration test? Also - where is the certificate file located?

Comment: Is in run-app, the certificate is located in the same folder as the Service Class is

Comment: I edited the answer based on your feedback - see if that works for you.